# Python json.loads(r.text) returns type <class 'list'>

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using `r = requests.post(something)`. I am expecting json to be returned.
Looking at `r.headers` I get back `'Content-Type': 'application/json' and 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'`.

When I perform `json.loads(r.text)` I am expecting an object of `dict` but instead, it is `<class 'list'>`
Any idea of why this does not create a dict?

The data returned looks like:

```
[{'contentId': '0ee022728af31b01', 'creationTS': 1484778192149,     
'updateTS': 1484778192188, 'lastUser': 'cmmigration', 'mimeType': 
'application/pdf', 'sourcePath': None, 'effectiveTS': None, 
'softDeleteTS': None, 'contentFileName': '[DRAFT] (null).pdf', 
'applicationId': 'ICX', 'currentState': 1, 'applicationName': 'ICX', 
'versionNum': 1, 'chronicleId': '0ee022728af31b00', 'expirationTS': 
1650030026000, 'versionLabel': 'WIP', 'contentFilePath': 
'/PO/2015/03/13/49412051/', 'lockDate': None, 'encryptedFlag': False, 
'authorId': 'migration', 'solrACLList': None, 'customAttributes': 
'{"r_object_id":"097b4c76800e5d55","icon_view_allow":"SP","subject":"Icon"
,"icon_pvendor":620418,"r_creation_date":"2015-04-17T09:40:28","ic_store_num":"xxxx","ic_mvendor":50031248,"ic_oded":"0","ic_upd_user_id":"txrxxx","icon_src_system":"I2GO","isanned":"0","icon_po_lead_date":"2015-04-13T20:35:06","language_code":"en_US","ic_user_id":"txrxxx","r_modify_date":"2015-04-17T09:40:29","i_po_num":"49412051","icon_bus_doc":750,"i_indexed":"0","icon_lead_num":"-1"}', 'softDeleteFlag': False, 'lockFlag': False, 'archiveTS': None, 'lockId': None, 'fileSize': 223062}]</pre>
```

Comment: You can see that the data is wrapped in `[]`, not `{}`, so it is an array (i.e., list) rather than an object (i.e., dict).

Comment: Note that you can do `r.json()` rather than `json.loads(r.text)`, although it will give the same result.

Comment: FYI, The requests package has a json convenience method that a bit more integrated with the request loop than rolling your own: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: Why are you expecting a dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That data *is* a list, though. `[{...}]` is a list that contains a single element, and that element is a dict.

If you want just the dict, do `my_dict = json.loads(r.text)[0]`.